# Ubuntu not working wifi

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I currently have ubuntu, I don’t understand Linux at all and my Wi-Fi network card doesn’t work: intel dual band wireless ac-7265 what should I do?

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `modinfo cfg80211; rfkill list; sudo dmesg|grep iwl`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.